# WCF serialization with specific format

Tags: c#, json, wcf, serialization

I am working on a WCF web services project.

I have a list of persons with their age that I need to return as a JSON. For that I am doing the following:

This is my service function:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(
    Method = "GET",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    UriTemplate = "GetPersons")]
Result GetPersons();
```

I have the `Person` Class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Age")]
    public int Age{ get; set; }
}
```

And a class `Result`:

```
[DataContract]
public class Result
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Persons")]
    public List<Person> Persons{ get; set; }
}
```

When returning the `Result` class I am getting this JSON form:

```
{"Persons":[{"Name" : "Tom", "Age" : 5 } , {"Name" : "Kate", "Age" : 8 }]}
```

Is there a way I can have this structure:

```
{"Persons":{"Tom" : 5, "Kate" : 8 }}
```

?

Basically I want the person names to be the key for the age.

I tried using a `Dictionary<string, int>` instead of the `Person` class but I am getting the following:

```
{"Persons":[{"Key" : "Tom", "Value" : 5 } , {"Key" : "Kate", "Value" : 8 }]}
```

How can I get the wanted JSON form? Is there a way to do it by using the WCF built in serialization or will I have to manually construct the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's impossible to tweak default data contract serialization, i see following solutions

1. change data contract serialization on [Newtonsoft.Json](http://json.codeplex.com/), here is [explanation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/03/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters.aspx) 
   On Newtonsoft.Json and create custom [JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base). Note you have to create JsonConverter for `Result` and `Person`. WCF's service contract isn't changed
2. Update WCF's service contract on `Stream GetPersons()` and create custom JsonConverter for `List<Person> Persons`. This way is simpler than 1st, because the serialization process is the same